# Adding Paypal button in Play framework Java 2.6

Tags: javascript, java, html, paypal, playframework

I am trying to implement the button of the payment method Paypal. So I wanted  to follow the [guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/orders-integration-guide/) on the website. I am using Java and the Play framework 2.6.

They give the following code on the website to add in your own code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="paypal-button"></div>

  <script>
    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'production', // Or 'sandbox',

        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        payment: function() {
            // Set up the payment here
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            // Execute the payment here
       }

    }, '#paypal-button');
  </script>
</body>
```

My code is a little bit different Because I have for the head a different file (called main.scala.html). So the main looks like this:

```
@*
* This template is called from the `index` template. This template
* handles the rendering of the page header and body tags. It takes
* two arguments, a `String` for the title of the page and an `Html`
* object to insert into the body of the page.
*@
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- These are the meta and scripts for paypal-->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" data-version-4></script>


        @* Here's where we render the page title `String`. *@
        <title>@title</title>

            <!-- Loading third party fonts -->
            <link href="@routes.Assets.versioned("fonts/another_font.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Loading weather css file -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/bootstrap.css")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/weather.css")">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")">

        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/bootstrap.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        @* And here's where we render the `Html` object containing
        * the page content. *@
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

The Content that gets called in the Main for the body looks like this:

```
    @main("ReStart") {
    <body>
            <!-- Payment Methods -->
                        @*TODO*@
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <h2>payment methodes</h2>
                            <div id="paypal-button"></div>

                            <script>
                                    paypal.button.render({

                                        env: 'production', // Or 'sandbox',

                                        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

                                        payment: function() {
                                            // Set up the payment here
                                        },

                                        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                                            // Execute the payment here
                                        }

                                    }, '#paypal-button');
                            </script>
                        </div>
        <!-- Required for the banner -->
        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js")"></script>

        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/plugins.js")"></script>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/app.js")"></script>

    </body>
}
```

In the Main file i added the meta and the script links. In the content file there is the call to render the button, but for some reason i just can't render it.

Things i tried:

1. Downloaded the checkout.js and used the following script tag

   ```
    <script src="@route.Assets.Versioned("javascript/checkout.js")"></script>
   ```
2. I tried the script tags (with link and downloaded js file) in both files. In the Main and in the content file.

It looks so simple but for some reason I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, where you have given the content you have written -

```
paypal.button.render
```

instead of

```
paypal.Button.render
```

The 'B' in button needs to be capital whereas you have used small. Fix that and see if it works. I hope I was of help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you remove off `HTML` style comments from your scala code.  I.e `<! - -  - - >` as it interferes with some scala methods instead use scala comments `@* *@`.
2. Change paypal button initialization script with capital B.
3. And do check if you are able to access Paypal js and css files from public directory. You can do it from `localhost:port/assets/rest_of_your_hierarchy`.